# Comparing 2 Cells and then based on their values Multiply another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet for my insurance business. I want to have a spreadsheet to determine my commission on a monthly basis. So I have one column for Line of Business (Auto, Home, etc) and then another column for Company they are written with (Company A, B, etc). Because each company pays differently I want to have the correct % multiplied.

For example, if Company A pays 10% commission for an Auto policy. I want it to look like this.

```
Line    Company    Premium   Commission

A         Co A       $1000      $100
```

But I want to be able to have Company B, C, etc with the correct % to multiply the Premium Column and then display in the commission column.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a table somewhere like this, give it the named range **"commission"**

```
Company A       10%
Company B       15%
Company C       20%
```

and then for the following data

```
A      B             C            D
Line   Company       Premium      Commission
A      Company A     1000
```

You could put the following formula in **D2**

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,commission,2,0)*$C2
```

Alternatively, if you didn't set up your named range, put the lookup table (Company A.. 10%.. etc) into another sheet (**Sheet 2, cell A1**) and use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0)*$C2
```

Info on named ranges, if needed:
http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/exceltips/qt/named_range.htm